# Update Label in function from dynamic string ? labelname + string

Tags: c#, label, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Form with several label controls :

```
lblBob
lblFred
lblGeorge
```

I would like to create a function to update these Labels something like this:

```
void SetLabelText (String first)
{
    Label test = lbl + first;
    test.Text = "hello";
}
```

the idea being I can run a job and gather first names then pass Bob or Fred or George to the function and update their relevant label by appending the passed string to the object name lbl?

obviously, the above fails due to can't add a string to label, so is it possible to do the above?

reason: form has over 20 labels to update and trying to reduce repeating code over and over by calling a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Controls.Find` to get the `Label`:

```
void SetLabelText (String first)
{
    Label test = Controls.Find("lbl" + first, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    if (test != null)
    {
        test.Text = "hello";
    }
}
```

You can read more here: [MSDN Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find)

Comment: @DmitryEgorov you're right, I've put the wrong link for documentation, and the Find returned an array, fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

why not just pass the label?

```
void SetLabelText(Label label, string text)
{
    label.Text = text;
}
```